# Keyboard buffering since OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, apple-mail

Since installing OS X 10.8 keyboard buffering when composing in Apple Mail has become a problem.  Sometimes I can key a six or eight letter word before it appears on the screen.  Mail is off right now and I am not encountering any buffering as I key this.

Comment: You might consider trying to formulate more of a question in order to elicit more of an answer.  Not really sure I'm understanding.  Does the buffering problem only occur within mail.app, or in any app, but only while mail is running?  Can you replicate this on demand?  More details please, and welcome to SU! :)

Answer (score 1):

In general since 10.8 keyboard buffering is a problem. I notice it in Safari. I used to open new tabs and start typing the address before the tab appeared. Now the system systematically ignores my keystrokes until focus is actually in the address bar.

Hopefully there is a preference hidden somewhere to get back to the old behaviour.

I just noticed this in TextEdit -- I hit <cmd>–S to save and start typing the name, but my typing is lost until the actual save dialog comes up.

For anyone who is tempted to criticise or down vote, just be aware that this page was the first or second result in Google when I searched for OS X keyboard buffer, so it would be good to provide an answer here if possible.

The question should read:

**Is there a way to return OS X 10.8 and later to the previous keystroke caching behaviour, where one could start typing before the text box appeared and keystrokes would appear once the window was ready?**